# Is there a way to make Get Latest in TFS behave like Get Specific Version of the latest checkin

Tags: version-control, visual-studio-2012

Whenever I `Get Latest` from TFS 2012 in Visual Studio. It doesn't really get latest. what it does is update the solution file so that new stuff added by my team mates shows up with a warning mark on in so say that its not there.

> FFS DIDN'T I JUST ASK TFS TO GET IT FOR ME!

Apparently TFS overcomplicates life by deciding based on some strange rules that I don't know what I am asking for and will give me what it thinks is right.

As far as I am concerned if the file has been modified since I last got it from the server GET IT! IT HAS CHANGED. Why would the source

Anyway I am wondering if there is a way to add a context menu command that will fire a `Get Specific Version` of the latest checkin?

It would save me a few failed builds and clicks and just generally being irritated by the Source Control System in TFS.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you select Get Latest *on the solution*, it will get the latest *of the solution*.  It won't get new items that were added to the solution on the server.

Instead, open Source Control Explorer and execute a Get Latest on the folder containing the solution.  This will get everything, the solution file, new files, etc.

As to why this is the case, I can only speculate:  Visual Studio solutions don't enforce a strict filesystem layout and one can place items anywhere in my filesystem into a solution.  So when you select Get Latest on a solution, the TFS provider will identify each item in your solution that is also in TFS and execute a Get Latest on those paths.  By doing this, new items would be excluded (because their paths were not specified in the get.)

New items *would* be included if you were to do a Get Latest on the paths themselves or the folder that contains them, however you can't know where these new items are until you've already done a get of the solution file.

So, if your solutions are set up such that all items are contained in some single directory (most, of course, are) then it's easiest just to use Get Latest from the Source Control Explorer.

Comment: Do you know why do 2 commands called Get Latest do different things?

Comment: I'm really interested to know the reason for this frustration :)

Comment: See the edited answer, above.  I can't speak (completely) authoritatively on this, because I work on the plug-in to Eclipse, which *does* have a nicely-enforced project layout thanks to the Java requirement that filenames and class names match.

Comment: They are not doing 2 different things. The Get Latest command will get the latest version of whatever your clicking on and all of its children. You can get latest on a file, a folder, or a branch. So the higher up the file tree you go, the more you get. The reason for this is simple, sometimes you may only want to get the latest version of a single file.

Comment: @aclear16: what you said is true about files and folders.  But a solution is a logical concept in Visual Studio that doesn't map directly to a concept in TFS.  (Well, it of course maps to a `.sln` file, but getting *just* the `.sln` when you clicked "Get Latest" on a solution would be a terrible experience.)  When you do a get latest on a solution, it tries to map that to the affected TFS files/folders.  But if somebody else adds a dependent resource in the directory containing your `.sln`, there's no way to know that.

Answer (score 0):

the option is built in here : rightclick -> advanced -> get specific version

curtesy of  http://hamidshahid.blogspot.co.uk/2012/12/get-specific-version-in-visual-studio.html

Comment: You didn't read the question. I want to do it in one click NOT open the Get specific version dialog, select a version and check the boxes. I want to right click and get the latest version from the server.

Answer (score -1):

I know this question has passed it's sell by date. But getting specific latest MOSTLY resolves the issues here on this end.

You should `Righ Click your sln File`
Go To `SourceControl` 
Click `Get Specific Version`

Make sure you `select the two check boxes` for Overwriting everything.

Comment: I didn't down vote you but I think you may have been down voted because my question specifically excludes this as an answer. 
The bit where I say "Anyway I am wondering if there is a way to add a context menu command that will fire a Get Specific Version of the latest checkin?" The answer is no btw.

Answer (score -2):

In TFS 2012, right click the project name, hover over "Advanced", and click "Get Specific Version..."

This answer is a bit belated, but to Peter, the commands are not the same. One is "Get Latest Version" and the other is "Get Specific Version...".

The real issue here is "Get Latest Version" does not get the latest version (odd, but true).

From a software engineering perspective, the "why" is easy. A project leader examined the requirements, analysis, code, and tests of these two menu options and said, "Okay!".

This is equally difficult to understand. Who was this person? The good news is that we can learn from other's mistakes or other's incomprehensible mistakes.

Comment: It absolutely gets the latest version.

Comment: Regularly, after a merge, after adding new files to a project, and after checking in pending changes and then making local changes, TFS will not update (overwrite) my local version with the server version. Doing a file compare will even show differences in my local version compared to the server version. It's a chain of events; it doesn't happen with new projects that haven't been branched (and then merged) or projects that don't change much from their creation. There's plenty of traffic online about these irregularities. I recommend more use of advanced features and some blog searches.

Comment: If you have a problem, it would be helpful if you would file a connect bug, post a stackoverflow question or reach out to a developer.  Then we can address your particular issues.