# How can I download new files on TFS 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to make Get Latest in TFS behave like Get Specific Version of the latest checkin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13634401/is-there-a-way-to-make-get-latest-in-tfs-behave-like-get-specific-version-of-the)

My environment is:

Visual Studio 2012 - Ultimate with SP1 and TFS 2012

My doubt:

When I click "Get Latest Version (Recursive)" on Solution menu, TFS only gets the files I already have downloaded. The new files, that other developer has checked in, appears like "Not downloaded" in Source Explorer. Look below.
How can I download this new files on "Get Latest Version (Recursive)"?

[image: TFS - Source Control]

Comment: What do you mean by "Solution menu"?

Comment: Solution menu: On Solution Explorer, right click on Solution Name.

Comment: If I open Source Control Explorer and execute a Get Latest on the folder containing the solution. This will get everything, the solution file, new files, etc. But this do not solve the problem.

Comment: What do you mean "this does not solve the problem"?

Comment: I meant, too many click to reach the objective. Is there a option "one-single-click" ?