# Getting latest version from Source Control Explorer VS Solution Explorer (Visual Studio and TFS)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, getlatest

How different is it from getting latest version from Source Control Explorer and Solution Explorer in Visual Studio. Some times when i get latest version through Solution explorer it does not get the exactly latest version for all the files. Any useful information is much helpful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to make Get Latest in TFS behave like Get Specific Version of the latest checkin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13634401/is-there-a-way-to-make-get-latest-in-tfs-behave-like-get-specific-version-of-the)

Comment: Glad to hear it - I realize it's not entirely obvious...!